# How to display in a form the next object of a collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of objects produced.
after click on next I want to display the next product in the form

in my asp page I have the following form:

```
<form id="formNF" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="txtRef" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtArticle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQauntity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:Button ID="ButtonNext" runat="server" Text="Next product" OnClick="ButtonNext_Click"/>
</form>
```

In my code-behind:

```
private int i; 
protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
     int nbrproducts = command.getListeproducts().Count; 
     i++; 
     for(i=0;i<nbrproducts;) { 
       mdeTxtRef.Text = command.getListeproducts()[i].Ref; 
       mdeTxtQte.Text = command.getListeproducts()[i].Qte; 
     } 
}
```

But it seems as ASP doesn't like this. Have u got an idea? thk u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can´t you iterate with a next()-method or something like this? List is serializable, so a simple for-loop with a counting integer and a page-reload should reach your aim.

Maybe your foreach-loop doesn´t stop, because a List-Object is open-ended, so it is running on empty List-places? Or did I misunderstood your problem? What did you mean with "continuing after click"?

for example:

```
//on button-click -->i++
for(int i=0;i<Products.size();)
{
//filling fields --> Products.get(i)
//reload page
}
```

A Buttonclick has also to initiate a Page-Reload.

EDIT:

Could it be, that your txtRef-Fields (in the foreach-loop) aren´t right, because you used 3 different fields?

Could you try do initiate an Integer-field or something like this, which could be iterated? When do you want to reset the List or its position? I´m not really into asp.net, so I don´t know, what properties and methods the List-Class got, but if there isn´t a simple next()-method, an iteration across the list should be enough. The function of this button should be no big deal.

Comment: Thank you, by"continuing after click" I mean going to the next item (product) and display it.

Comment: I'm too a beginner in asp, there is not next() method.

private int i;
protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int nbrproducts = command.getListeproducts().Count;
            
            i++;
            for(i=0;i<nbrStocks;) 
            { 
                mdeTxtRef.Text = command.getListeproducts()[i].Ref;
                mdeTxtQte.Text = command.getListeproducts()[i].Qte;
            } 
        }
But ASP doesn't like this. Have u got an idea? thk u.

Comment: Is their any useful error thrown?
Could you define a global integer, so clicking the button only increases the integer and refreshes the page (including the have-to-be-updated-fields). The fields itself references to the global integer, that every new value of this integer is leading to a changed field-value.